# Can't get rid of Google's pagespeed insights warnings (the website has a blocking css)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagespeed

When checking my website on Google's page-speed insights, it gives me alert, that the website has a blocking css: [Google pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwoohoocasino.com%2F&tab=mobile). This is the code I have:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

I tried to move it into the body, right before `</body>`, but it didn't help, it even reduced the points. What can be done to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks and PageSpeed don't mix too well.
From [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change)
**Note that Turbolinks will only consider tracked assets in `<head>` and not elsewhere on the page.**

From [Google's Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css%20pagespeed%20insites)
**By default, CSS is treated as a render blocking resource.**

Rails, by default, hurts the PageSpeed. Some people put the "critical" CSS inline in the `<head>` and the link to the rest before `</body>`. But as stated turbolinks won't track assets outside of `<head>`.

A solution I've seen
*application.html.erb*

```
<style>
  <%= raw File.read("public" + asset_path("application.css")) %>
</style>
```

That puts all the CSS inline. Probably not the best solution but it does improves PageSpeed.
I've seen sites that do that with JS too.